# Where do I get a readable stack trace in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

The following is the exception I get from iOS. It looks ridiculously unreadable (my brain is screaming wtf ten thousand miles per second). So this can’t be right. When I am developing for android, and I get an exception, the stack trace is completely readable, no magic such as `0x187d27bc8`. So am I looking at the wrong window? Where in Xcode to I go to find a readable version of my stack trace? In eclipse there is a line number I can click on to get to the exact line that caused the error.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1835a6084 0x193b840e4 0x18348f300 0x18349b5b8 0x100185c94 0x100185af4 0x10009f7b4 0x10009ede4 0x10009ec9c 0x10006c5a0 0x1882f32b8 0x10006c358 0x187d5d2f4 0x187d4644c 0x187d5cc90 0x187d1c724 0x187d567b8 0x187d55e58 0x187d29660 0x187fc7d6c 0x187d27bc8 0x18355e324 0x18355d5c8 0x18355b678 0x183489664 0x18c5cb5a4 0x187d8e984 0x100139854 0x1941f2a08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 4):

In your menu bar go to: `Debug -> BreakPoints -> Create Exception BreakPoints`. And that should do it. So the next time you run the code, it will stop at the line that caused the exception. And then to the left, you should see the stack trace.